# How to serialize Firestore TimeStamp in Android Java?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am passing a Class as Extras and the class has TimeStamp as a member and getting the following error, how to serialize TimeStamp?

**Error:**

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.firebase.Timestamp
```

Comment: The class that you pass as Extras extends Serializable ? because `com.google.firebase.Timestamp` implements `Parcelable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) contains just two numbers, seconds and nanoseconds.  You can serialize them each separately, then recreate the Timestamp using its [constructor that takes both values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp).  Or you can take advantage of the fact that it's [Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable).

Answer (score 0):

convert it to date `Date myDate=timeStamp.ToDate()` and serialize if you want to convert bake to timestamp you can use `new Timestamp(myDate)`