# Firestore TimeStamp passed through Callable functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a react web app that helps with project management. The issue I'm facing is around the timestamps of Firestore. Each project object stored in Firestore has a `createdOn` field that is of type Firestore timestamp. My web app is calling a callable firebase function which gets all the projects and returns them. The issue is the `toDate()` function doesn't work in the web app but it works in the firebase functions. I'm wondering if the problem is when converting to JSON that timeStamp loses something. Am I missing something or should I be storing them as something?  I really don't want to convert all the dates server side as that would slow down the function call. I am using the timestamp to filter on the client side and for analytics.

How I'm writing the time stamp as part of the project object: `createdOn: admin.firestore.Timestamp.now(),`

and in the callable function I'm testing with this: `console.log(allProjects[0].createdOn!.toDate())` and this works.

In my web app I'm calling this `data.createdOn.toDate()`  and getting the error `TypeError: data.createdOn.toDate is not a function`

Any help would be appreciated. 
thanks,

I'm using on the functions side

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.0.0",
"firebase-functions": "^2.3.1",
```

and client side

```
"firebase": "^6.1.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.1"
"react": "^16.8.6",
```

Comment: have u checked if the timestamp is being saved on the database as a string or a timestamp? they get tricky if they are being saved as string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"I'm wondering if the problem is when converting to JSON that timeStamp loses something."*

Yes, it loses something.  The Timestamp will be serialized in such a way that its seconds and nanoseconds fields will be sent individually.  You will have to reconstitute a [new Timestamp object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp.html#constructor) from those values received on the client.  Since you're not showing very specific code, it's not really possible to give more information.  I strongly suggest you not just depend on the default JSON serialization of a Timestamp, and instead specifically read and write its seconds and nanoseconds fields explicitly on both ends.

See also this related question for Java: [How to serialize Firestore TimeStamp in Android Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56409756/how-to-serialize-firestore-timestamp-in-android-java/56410111#56410111)

Comment: I wish firebase would work this into the callable functions, to send a timestamp correctly but until then I just reconstructed a timestamp and it worked.  thanks.

Comment: You can certainly file a feature request for that.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support